# iOS: How to display Touch Id icon in a virtual keypad

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

How to display touch Id option inside a virtual keypad? Is it possible with alpha-numeric keypad as well?

[image]

Comment: That would definitely be cool, but there are restrictions to keyboards in iOS, though. Have you seen it done in any other apps?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this in Discover app..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but you will have to create the keyboard yourself. I had to do this to add a "done" button to the keyboard. If interested I can make this code available to you.